# Dimension of affine springer fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory

I have a few questions with respect to Bezrukavnikov's proof of the dimension formula for affine springer fibers in *Fixed point set on affine flag manifolds*. The setting is as follows: Let G be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F=\mathbb{C}((t))$ with the valuation that satisfies $\nu_F(t)=1$, and $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{C}[[t]]$. Let $N\in g(\mathcal{O})$ be a regular semisimple nil-element. Let $Z(N)$(resp $z(N))$ be the centralizer of $N$ in $G(F)$(resp $g(F)$). Let $M$ be the lattice of integral elements in $z(N)$, here $x\in g(F)$ is integral means that for any $Q$ an ad-invarant polynomial of $g$, $Q(x)\in \mathcal{O}$. Then 
$$
\dim(Z(N)/Z(N)\cap G(\mathcal{O}))=\dim(M/M\cap g(\mathcal{O}))=\frac{1}{2}(\nu_F(\det(k|M\cap g(\mathcal{O}))-\nu_F(\det(k|M)))
$$
Here $k$ is the killing form. Why are those two equalities true?

Comment: It may be simplest here to ask Roman B. himself (?); he can usually be reached by email even if he's not at MIT.   By the way, that paper is here: http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0003/0002/a005/